# Putting focus on a textbox in onchange event

Tags: javascript, events, textbox, focus, onchange

I am trying to get it so that when a certain value is put into a textbox, the focus will stay on the textbox(and an alert will be shown in production). I am trying to get this to work in Firefox 3.5.7 with no luck.

How can I make it so when a textbox is a certain value at `onchange` that it will stay focused/refocus on the textbox?

Live example is at http://jsbin.com/ipina

```
<body>
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onchange="
  if(this.value=='foo'){
    this.select();
    this.focus();
  }
  "  />
</body>
```

Also, I don't get any javascript errors or warnings in the Error Console on executing this code.

Comment: Are you trying to force focus to stay on that textbox?  Wouldn't it have focus if the user is changing it?

Comment: No, the onchange event will not be called(in firefox and IE for textboxes) until the control loses focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Javascript onchange different in IE and FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058249/javascript-onchange-different-in-ie-and-firefox) I needed to set the focus after the onchange event occurs, so I had to end up with something like this:

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="
  if(this.value=='foo'){
    alert('bah');
    setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'fname\').focus();document.getElementById(\'fname\').select();',0);
  }
  "  />
```

And also I had to catch it when the focus was lost, not necessarily when the text was changed, so I had to use onblur instead of onchange.

Live: http://jsbin.com/ofeva

Answer (score 2):

When the `onchange` event is fired, the user is focused on the textbox.

Maybe you might want to use the `blur` event to re-focus on the textbox if the value is 'foo'.

If you need instantaneous results, you should use `onkeyup`.

```
<body>
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onkeyup="
  if(this.value=='foo'){
    this.select();
    this.focus();
  }
  "  />
</body>
```

Comment: I need the whole value to be entered before I can evaluate if the textbox should remain focused or not.