# Javascript focus to text box

Tags: javascript

I have wrote onchange event to the text box. in that if the value is less than 10 means i have to focus the cursor to text box for that i tried

```
  function myFunctionId (elt) {
       alert(elt.id);
        if(elt.value < 10) { alert(elt.value);
       document.getElementById("tester").focus();
        }    
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dRkuv/588/

but that focus is not working. How would i achieve this?

Comment: in your fiddle your html is wrong, input is just one tag.

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097840/putting-focus-on-a-textbox-in-onchange-event

Regardless, here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/dRkuv/591/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround

```
function myFunctionId (elt) {
    if(elt.value < 10) { 
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            elt.focus();
        },0);
    }    
}
```

myFunction is called just before elt lost focus so if you call focus on it, it doesn't work. But if you use setTimeout function it would be called a little bit later.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong this is what you want in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" onchange="myFunctionId(this);" id="tester" placeholder="Pass Element">
```

In the Javscript it should be `elt.value.length <10` and you need to setTimeOut to prevent  the text cursor from not showing:

```
function myFunctionId (elt) {
   console.log(elt.id);
    if(elt.value.length < 10) {
     console.log(elt.value);
     setTimeout(function(){
        elt.focus(); 
     },1);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunctionId (elt) {
var val=document.getElementById("tester").value;

       alert(elt.id);
        if(val < 10) { alert(val);
       document.getElementById("tester").focus();
       return false;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this http://jsfiddle.net/shashankreddy09/dRkuv/615/


    var interval;
        var i=0;
        function myFunctionId (elt) {
           console.log(elt.id);
            if(elt.value.length < 10) { //if ur checkin the sting length if its a number use //elt.value<10
             console.log(elt.value);
              interval=setInterval(function(){elt.focus();
                                             i++;
                                             if(i>1)
                                               clearInterval(interval);  },0);
            }   


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`onblur="myFunctionId(this);"` in text field

```
function myFunctionId (elt) {
   //alert(elt.id);
    if(elt.value.length < 10) { alert(elt.value);
   elt.focus();
    }    
}
```